# Kafka producer with default partitioning

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Right now my kafka producer is sinking all the messages to a single partition of a kafka topic which actually have more than 1 partition.

How can i create a producer that will use the default partitioner and distribute the messages among different partitions of the topic.

Code snippet of my kafka producer:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrap.servers);
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
```

I am using flink kafka producer to sink the messages on kafka topic.

```
speStream.addSink(
    new FlinkKafkaProducer011(kafkaTopicName,
    new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper<>(new SimpleStringSchema()), 
    props, 
    FlinkKafkaProducer011.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the default partitioner, messages are assigned a partition using the following logic:

- keyed messages: a hash of the key is generated and based on that a partition is selected. That means messages with the same key will end up on the same partition
- unkeyed messages: round robin is used to assign partitions

One option that explain the behaviour you see is if you're using the same key for all your messages, then with the default partitioner they will end up on the same partition.

Comment: I am not sure about the key part here. I am using flink kafka producer to sink the messages on kafka topic.                                                                                                                                                 speStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011(kafkaTopicName,new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper<>(new SimpleStringSchema()), props, FlinkKafkaProducer011.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE));

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by changing the flinkproducer to

speStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011(kafkaTopicName,new SimpleStringSchema(), props));

Comment: The FlinkPartitloner is different than Kafka partitioner